# 50-cloud-init.yaml don't apply at boot

Tags: boot, dhcp, netplan

i have a ubuntu 18.04 server machine with 2 eth ports. Eth1 have a static ip then eth2 could be in 3 different config: dhcp-static-bridge (with eth1).
I made a script that starts at every boot and checks USB port to eventually replace /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml to restore my default configuration.
On reboot the 50-cloud-init.yaml has actually changed but my eth2 don't take an ip address until the second reboot.
This happens only if the previous config was in bridge mode, when the previous config of my eth2 was static, eth2 take an address at the first reboot.
This is my script that start with crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/.bash_profile
echo "Mount usb..">>/var/log/example/reset.log
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/USB 
DIR=/media/USB
FILE=$DIR/__EXAMPLE.reset
if test -f "$FILE"; then
    echo "$FILE exists." >> /var/log/example/reset.log
    cp $FILE /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
    #/usr/sbin/netplan apply 
    ip link set enp1s0 up 
    ip link set enp2s0 up 
    ip link set br0 down 
    /sbin/brctl delbr br0 
    /usr/sbin/netplan 
    redis-cli -n 1 set __EXAMPLE.lan_config dhcp 
    rm /opt/example/example_web_config/machine_configs.json
    echo "{\"machines\":[]}" >> /opt/example/example_web_config/machine_configs.json
fi
```

This is my usb default configuration

```
network:
ethernets:
    enp1s0:
        dhcp4: no
        optional: true
        addresses: [10.0.0.10/24]
        gateway4: 10.0.0.1
        nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
    enp2s0:
        dhcp4: yes
        optional: true
version: 2
```

Comment: In your script you are calling 'netplan' and the call to 'netplan apply' is commented out.  Why is this?  You don't appear to be applying the newly-written netplan yaml as part of your script.

Comment: i was just testing but doesn't work anyway even with netplan apply in the script

Comment: For further debugging, you'll want to call `netplan apply` then see what the state of networkd is (what files created under /run/systemd/network, etc)